# how to define global scope event handler for React server-side rendering

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-rendering, react-server

Comparing with client side rendering, I prefer to use server-side rendering for an application with little user-interaction.and webpack is the choice for compiling server side code.

There is a scenario I want to update table's ***marginTop*** once the component is rendered. If it is client-side rendering, the implementation will be listed as follows

```
componentDidMount() {
  const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.table);
  node.style.marginTop = `-${height}`;
}
```

However, on ssr, **componentDidMount** are never be called when the component is rendered. So i put these codes in **componentWillMount**, and update source code as follows

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  const node = document.getElementById('table');
  node.style.marginTop = `-${height}`;
});
```

then it has other issue.

```
document is not defined on server
```

I know the reason, it is because the code is running on node environment. there is no **document** variety like browser environment. A way I can think out is to put the code in the **renderPage function** which is used to render React component to html string on server side [Server Rendering](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html). But if a put the event handler on the top-level context, it will pollute other rendered page.

```
router.get('*', ctx => {
  match({ routes: routes, location: ctx.url }, (err, redirect, props) => {
    if (err) {
      ctx.throw(err.message, 500);
    } else if (redirect) {
      ctx.redirect(redirect.pathname + redirect.search)
    } else if (props) {
      const appHtml = renderToString(<RouterContext {...props}/>);
      ctx.body = renderPage(appHtml);
    } else {
      ctx.throw(404, 'not fount');
    }
  })
})
function renderPage(appHtml) {
  return `
    <!doctype html public="storage">
    <html>
    <meta charset=utf-8/>
    <title>My First React Router App</title>
    <div id=app>${appHtml}</div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        const node = document.getElementById('table');
        node.style.marginTop = `-${height}`;
      });
    </script>
  `
}
```

I have also found other resolution. [A React component for binding events on the global scope.](https://github.com/oliviertassinari/react-event-listener). I dont think its the best resolution.

So I want to ask is there a better way to manipulate DOM node which is normally put in **componentDidMount** or **componentDidUpdate** like client-side rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulate DOM node this way like you do is useless. React take over controll of your DOM, after next time you re-render your app the margin you set is going to be override by React.

I recommend you use inline style to manipulate whatever style you like to tackle.

```
render() {
  const divStyle={'marginTop': '100px'}

  return <div style={divStyle}></div>
}
```

Also let render function take care of UI stuff.

Is there any reason you need to reset marginTop in React lifecycle but not in render function directly?